# Generate random alphanumeric string in formatted sequence

Tags: java, random

Please how do I generate a string of random numbers in Java in this formatted order. The string is 5 characters in length (as specified in the format below)

letter-letter-digit-digit-digit

Every single one of the characters is to be random but in the format specified above.

This is code I am currently having issues with: For one, it prints 50 random characters from alphabet.

```
import java.util.Random;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
         Random r = new Random();

         String[] alphabet = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};
         int[]    number = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
         for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
             System.out.printf("%s,%s,%d,%d,%d\n", 
               alphabet[i].charAt(r.nextInt(alphabet.length())), 
               number[i].charAt(r.nextInt(number.length())) );
         } // prints 50 random characters from alphabet
     }
}
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: What is your issue with the current code?

Comment: Note that your introduction uses dashes (`-`) between the five parts while the `printf()` uses commas. (The name of the class is irritating.)

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
public class Try{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println("Generated String : " + generate());
  }

  public static int random(int low, int high){
    return ((int)(Math.random()*(high-low)) + low);
  }

  public static String generate(){
    String result = "";
    result += (char)random(65, 91);
    result += (char)random(65, 91);
    result += random(0, 10);
    result += random(0, 10);
    result += random(0, 10);
    return result;
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
┌─[jaysmito@parrot]─[~]
└──╼ $java Try.java
Generated String : UX426
┌─[jaysmito@parrot]─[~]
└──╼ $java Try.java
Generated String : NJ662
```